# Convert RGB to 8 bit

Tags: bash, algorithm, colors, rgb

So, i'm creating a  graphical Bash PS1 Generator using Javascript. The user can select any color from a palette (jscolor library) for any element they want. The value i'm getting is the RGB represantion of that color. I would like to convert that value to a number between 0-255 so it can be represented in Bash.

Example:

Input: #000000

Output: 0

Input: #FFFFFF

Output: 255

Any other input converted to the closest 8 bit representation

**I checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807669/how-to-convert-an-rgb-color-to-the-closest-matching-8-bit-color) but the answers aren't quite working(I'm getting output 215 for input #FFFFFF).

Comment: The problem you're going to run into is that you're going to "lose" some colors, and there's not a great way to "lose" them evenly. If you compressed each 8-bit color component value into 3 bits, you'd still have to discard one of them (either red, green, or blue) to fit into 8 bits. If you compressed them down into 2 bits, you could "keep" color balances, but you'd have pretty "grainy" color resolution.

Comment: @mojo In your opinion, should i give the users limited color options(red,green,blue,gray etc) ?

Comment: It kind of depends on what you want to do with these colors. There are several ways of dealing with colors. GIF, for example uses the 8-bit value as a reference to a 24-bit color value. You can only have 256 unique colors in any GIF, but they can be any of the 16 million 24-bit colors.

Comment: I once wrote a [function](https://github.com/bewuethr/bash-raytracer/blob/master/raytracer#L155) that does that for a terminal-based ray tracer, but in Bash. I used [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27159322/3266847) for the algorithm.

Comment: see [Dithering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36820654/2521214)

Answer (score 2):

You're getting output 215 for 0xFFFFFF due to used palette.

So-named "web-safe" palette contains 216 (6^3) colors formed with component grades `(ir * 255/5, ig * 255/5, ib * 255/5)` for impacts `ir,ig,ib = 0..5`, and 40 additional colors like "money green" or "tender salmon".

So index 215 of such palette really contains `0xFFFFFF` RGB.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (bad) idea:

```
let rgb24=0x99FFBB
let r2="($rgb24 >> 16) >> 6"
echo "$r2"
let g2="(($rgb24 >> 8) % 256) >> 6"
echo "$g2"
let b2="($rgb24 % 256) >> 6"
echo "$b2"

let rgb8="($r2 << 4) + ($g2 << 2) + $b2"

printf "%x\n" $rgb24
printf "%x\n" $rgb8
```

So now, you've got two bits color intensity for each: red, green, and blue.

How you display such a thing is kind of up to you. The simplest thing to do would be to bit shift each component color by 6 and then reconstruct the original 24-bit color value. You'd have a total of four different intensities for each color, or 64 unique colors.